# `sandwich::vcovCL` does not equal `AER::tobit` standard errors

Tags: r

Help! I'm not sure why these don't equal each other. Varying to HC0 nad HC1 doesn't help either. Example below:

```
pacman::pload(sandwich, AER, tidyverse)

set.seed(505)
test_d <- tibble(x=rnorm(500),
               cluster=sample(seq(1,100),size=500,replace=T),
               y=-cluster/10+.2*x+rnorm(500)) %>% 
  mutate(y=ifelse(y<0,0,y))

m <- AER::tobit(y~x,
           data = test_d,
           cluster=cluster)
summary(m)
cf_test <- coeftest(m,vcov. = vcovCL(m,
                          cluster = ~cluster))

tribble(~"method",~"se_intercept",~"se_x",~"se_log(scale)",
        "AER::tobit",summary(m)$coefficient[1,2],summary(m)$coefficient[2,2],summary(m)$coefficient[3,2],
        "vcovCL",cf_test[1,2], cf_test[2,2],cf_test[3,2]
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source of the bug:** The reason is that your fitted model already computes the clustered covariance matrix itself which the `sandwich` package did not detect. Hence it uses the full clustered covariance as the "bread" in the sandwich (rather than the naive covariance).

**How to avoid it:** With the current CRAN versions of the packages, it's easiest to avoid the problem by applying `vcovCL()` only to models fitted **without** the `cluster` argument. Then the result (with the right cluster adjustment) agrees with the `vcov()` on the clustered model:

```
m0 <- AER::tobit(y ~ x, data = test_d)
vcovCL(m0, cluster = ~ cluster, cadjust = FALSE)
##             (Intercept)            x   Log(scale)
## (Intercept)  0.22307101 -0.014202428 -0.067311156
## x           -0.01420243  0.010922194  0.006217075
## Log(scale)  -0.06731116  0.006217075  0.023430960
vcov(m)
##             (Intercept)            x   Log(scale)
## (Intercept)  0.22307101 -0.014202428 -0.067311156
## x           -0.01420243  0.010922194  0.006217075
## Log(scale)  -0.06731116  0.006217075  0.023430960
```

**Bug fix:** I have adapted the `bread()` extractor functions for `survreg` objects (in `sandwich`) and for `tobit` objects (in `AER`) in the development versions of the packages. So with the next CRAN release (not scheduled yet) the bug will be avoided automatically - even if the model was estimated with a `cluster` argument.